# Passing a timezone on \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat does not have any effect

Tags: php

I'm using php8.2 and I have some trouble comparing dates inside a composer package running on my CI.
In short, the date comparison in php is failing because the timezone is not the expected one.

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(\date_default_timezone_get());
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable('now', $timezone);
$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('U.u', $now->format('U.u'), $timezone);
var_dump($now, $date, $now === $date, $now > $date, $now < $date);
```

The code inside the package is creating a DateTimeImmutable Object for the current date and compares another DateTimeImmutable coming from a UNIX timestamp. However, the timezone for the  DateTimeImmutable coming from a UNIX timestamp is ignoring the passed timezone Object.

The result looks like this:

```
...BearerTokenValidatorTest.php:61:
class DateTimeImmutable#445 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2023-09-28 12:20:51.615050"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
...BearerTokenValidatorTest.php:61:
class DateTimeImmutable#444 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2023-09-28 10:20:51.615050"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(1)
  public $timezone =>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
...BearerTokenValidatorTest.php:61:
bool(false)
...BearerTokenValidatorTest.php:61:
bool(false)
...BearerTokenValidatorTest.php:61:
bool(false)
```

Interestingly, each comparison is false.

The original code I'm using and creates trouble can be found here: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/5.1.x/src/Token/Parser.php#L160C69-L160C69

Comment: Appears to be related to the `U.u.` format ...? If I replace this with `$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '2023-09-28 12:40:21.018835', $timezone);`, then I am getting the same time zone for both - `Europe/Amsterdam` specifically, when executed at https://3v4l.org/PqTT5

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to how DateTimeImmutable objects are compared in PHP. When comparing two DateTimeImmutable objects using ===, PHP compares not only the date and time but also the timezone.

In your code, $now has the timezone set to "Europe/Berlin," and $date has the timezone set to "+00:00" (UTC). When you compare them using ===, PHP checks if both the date/time and the timezone are identical, which is why the comparison returns false.

If you want to compare DateTimeImmutable objects based on their date and time, ignoring the timezone, you can convert both objects to UTC before comparing them. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(\date_default_timezone_get());
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable('now', $timezone);
$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('U.u', $now->format('U.u'), $timezone);

// Convert both DateTimeImmutable objects to UTC
$nowUtc = $now->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateUtc = $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

var_dump($nowUtc, $dateUtc, $nowUtc == $dateUtc, $nowUtc > $dateUtc, $nowUtc < $dateUtc);
```

By setting both $now and $date to the UTC timezone before comparing them, you will ignore the timezone difference, and the comparison should work as expected.

Note that I used == for equality comparison instead of === because you want to compare the date and time values, and not necessarily the object references.

Comment: This looks a lot like an AI-generated answer. fyi: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Valid, but unfortunately, the bundle I'm using is working with U.u format as it validates jwt: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/5.1.x/src/Token/Parser.php#L160C69-L160C69

Answer (score 0):

The `===` operator will always return `false` for even identical objects:

```
$a = new \DateTime('2020-01-01 12:34:56 UTC');
$b = clone $a;
var_dump($a, $b, $a === $b);
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-01-01 12:34:56.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-01-01 12:34:56.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
bool(false)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0nA2T#v8.2.10) and [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php).

> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

You can use `==`, even though the definition suggest it wouldn't work:

> Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and are instances of the same class.

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(\date_default_timezone_get());
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable('now', $timezone);
$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('U.u', $now->format('U.u'), $timezone);
var_dump($now, $date, $now == $date);
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable('next year', $timezone);
var_dump($now, $date, $now == $date);
```

```
object(DateTimeImmutable)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2023-09-29 13:59:39.005630"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTimeImmutable)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2023-09-29 11:59:39.005630"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
bool(true)
object(DateTimeImmutable)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2024-09-29 13:59:39.005746"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTimeImmutable)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2023-09-29 11:59:39.005630"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
bool(false)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/T4UFN#v8.2.10)

Aside this, during my experience with date/time comparisons in PHP I've encountered a couple of rare bugs when dealing with daylight saving time boundaries, so if you want to be extra sure you can always normalise data convert everything to UTC before comparison, or extract the Unix time and compare that.